# Excel Web Part Display Issues

Tags: chart-web-part

I'm creating a new SharePoint site for my team and I don't know much about SharePoint. My first order of business is to put a dashboard on the site. The dashboard is currently a bunch of charts in Excel. I did a little googling and learned how to get a dashboard set up using web parts but it only shows one chart at a time with a dropdown menu to change the chart. Also it's showing charts from the first and second sheet in the worksheet but not the third. I only need the charts from the first worksheet.

Does anyone know how to:

- Increase the display area to be the majority of the page rather than just like 5/16 of the page?
- Show more than one chart at a time (preferably side by side)?
- Select only certain charts to be shown?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that in the properties you can adjust the size by pixels, for some reason when I tried this before I thought it wasn't what I wanted.

I also realized that there is an option to not show the dropdown menu, so I can simply have multiple web parts with each one calling a specific chart.